# javascript regex ending string with values in array

Tags: javascript, forms

I've to check if my string value is ending with `".com"` or `".de"`
I've put this values inside array:

```
var valuesEnd = [".com", ".de"]
```

My value to compare is taken from form. Also it has to check for @ sign, it must have.

Comment: Do you want to check your string against only `.com` and `.de` or there could be other items in the array?

Comment: Email should ending with this values from an array .com or .de

Comment: Just those or there could be others in the array??

Comment: only those, nothing more than is inside array

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: I think there's a jQuery plugin for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: I've created a new jQuery plugin for you to use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42355740/5870134.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RegExp#test`.

```js
var str = ['abc.de', 'wok.pl', 'qwdok.com'];

console.log(str.map(v => /\w+\.(de|com)$/g.test(v) ? v + ' is valid' : v + ' is invalid'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like this:

```js
var str = prompt("Email: ");

if(/\.(?:com|de)$/.test(str))
  alert("'" + str + "' is valid");
else
  alert("'" + str + "' is not valid");
```

Comment: there must be also sign @ in email

Answer (score 0):

I've created a jQuery plugin for you:

```
(function($) {
  // the string object (NOTE: it can be extended)
  $.string = {};
  // "create" a new string
  $.string.new = function(string) {
    return string;
  };
  // test a string for a regex match
  $.string.test = function(string, regex) {
    return regex.test(string);
  };
  // join three strings together
  $.string.join = function(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
  };
  // log a string to the console
  $.string.log = function(string) {
    console.log(string);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Then you would use the plugin like this:

```
// for test purposes we'll be using: "example@example.com"
var email = $.string.new("example@example.com");
// check to see if the email is valid or not
if($.string.test(email, /\@.*?\.(?:com|de)$/)) {
  // let us know that the email is valid
  $.string.log($.string.join("'", email, "' is a valid email."));
}
// if this block runs the email is invalid
else {
  // let us know that this is an invalid email
  $.string.log($.string.join("'", email, "' is not a valid email."));
}
```